# $apply and $digest working same or not please understand?

Tags: angularjs

```
I have Confusion in $digest when we need to used ? But $apply I think we need when angular js into any element have outside scope then we use $apply and update it with value.
```

$digest means same But How can we use so, we used differently.

internally $digest call in this code.

Comment: < button ng-click="updateTime()">update time - ng-click < /button>
    
$scope.updateTime = function() {
$scope.data.time = new Date();
}

Answer (score 1):

`$apply()` - Internally calls `$digest` just the difference is it's $digest cycle starts from the rootscope and visit all child element(their model) and calls $digest on them.

Comment: rootscope when start $digest cycle ?